# Replumb sillcocks to increase outdoor pressure?

Tags: plumbing, irrigation

I'm trying to increase pressure to my outside hoses for lawn watering and noticed that the sillcocks are all after my whole house water filter and they are all 1/2". Because of this, when I run the sprinklers, the whole house filter gets dirty and clogged very quickly. The plumbing from my well pressure tank is 3/4" and the pressure switch is set to 40/60.

Would I see a worthwhile pressure and flow increase to my outside impact sprinklers if I:

- Plumb in a 3/4" tee before the whole house filter and run 1" PEX lines to sillcock valves
- Replace existing 1/2" sillcocks with 3/4" sillcocks
- Run 3/4" hose from sillcock to impact sprinklers

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best improvement would come from adding the tee before the filter and running the new PEX to the sillcocks.  I would hold off on replacing the sillcocks at the same time as adding the tee because you might not need to depending on the results from the tee. Plus, the 3/4" sillcocks might not fit through your brick walls. Do this in stages.

Comment: ...but depending what is clogging the whole-house filter now, you may have problems with "dirt" (currently being filtered out) plugging up the sprinklers. My "first filter" is a "spin-down" that traps debris where it can be removed by opening a valve, rather than needing a new element every time - there's a filter screen, but that gets cleared when dumping the collected gunk. Seems like someitng similar as a pre-filter might prolong the life of your current filters.

Comment: I agree with this answer and with @Ecnerwal comment except that debris may *not* be an issue for impact sprinklers because they typically have a large orifice. However, a low-restriction filter might be needed if in future the teed line is used for something else.